# Detecting clicks on multiple markers in mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am working with mapbox markers and I have created multiple markers as follows:

```
var cord = [{lng:,lat:},{lng:,lat:}]
function createMarker(){
   for(var i = 0; i < cord.length; i++){
     var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({})
                    .setLngLat([cord[i].lng, cord[i].lat])
                    .addTo(map);
   }
}
```

I wanted each marker to detect the click but I am unable to figure out how to do it?

Is it possible to detect click on each marker ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a click event handler like this:

```js
marker.element.addEventListener('click', event => alert('click'));
```

Comment: hello @SteveBennett, thank you for the answer. i wanted to perform different actions on both the markers. is there a way to detect that whether the first marker is clicked or the second marker?

Comment: The best option for this would be to specify an options.element for each Marker instance (documented as an optional parameter here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker) so that the HTML element for each Marker would have an ID which you can use to specify unique click listeners.

Comment: Hello @AdrianaBabakanian, thanks for the reply. But can you please show me an example of what you meant exactly,as I can only see the default options present on the link you specified?

Comment: The first parameter in the Marker documentation is options.element. This parameter allows you to specify a DOM element to use as the marker. This example in the Mapbox GL JS documentation shows how to use the optional element parameter in detail: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/. In general, I'd recommend taking a look at the GL JS examples page for guidance on how to use particular methods and parameters, since there are many robust examples there: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/examples/.

Comment: @AdrianaBabakanian got your point, everything worked , but the I had to change the default "blue symbol" of the marker to a custom image of mine. Is there a way to not to change to a custom image of marker and use the default blue symbol only and yet achieve the multiple click functionality which I want to achieve?